# The button reopens when clicked Jquery JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying the following: when a user clicks on a button, a value opens. If the other button was already open, it closes.

The result is the following: if I open one, the previous one is closed.

The problem is that if I try to close the same button I opened, it reopens its contents.

Can someone tell me why it happens?

```js
$(".btnCategory").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).find('.infoSubCategory');
    $('.infoSubCategory').not(target).slideUp();
    target.slideToggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<row class="col-xs-12" id="row1">
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 btnCategory">
           
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btnCategory">
   <a class="">BUTTON 1</a>
  </button>

  <div class="infoSubCategory">
                     
     <li><a>Value 1</a></li>
  
    </div>
  </div>

</row>

<row class="col-xs-12" id="row2">
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 btnCategory">
           
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btnCategory">
   <a class="">BUTTON 2</a>
  </button>

  <div class="infoSubCategory">
                     
     <li><a>Value 2</a></li>
  
    </div>
  </div>

</row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, it is causing an error because you are using the same class name `btnCategory` for the wrapper and also the button.

```js
$(".btnCategory").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).parent().find('.infoSubCategory');
    $('.infoSubCategory').not(target).slideUp();
    target.slideToggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<row class="col-xs-12" id="row1">
  
  <div class="col-xs-6">
           
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btnCategory">
   <a class="">BUTTON 1</a>
  </button>

  <div class="infoSubCategory">
                     
     <li><a>Value 1</a></li>
  
    </div>
  </div>

</row>

<row class="col-xs-12" id="row2">
  
  <div class="col-xs-6">
           
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btnCategory">
   <a class="">BUTTON 2</a>
  </button>

  <div class="infoSubCategory">
                     
     <li><a>Value 2</a></li>
  
    </div>
  </div>

</row>
```